# Automatically obfuscate internals and private members with ConfuserEx

Tags: c#, .net, confuserex

If I am using `ConfuserEx`, will it automatically obfuscate all internal and private members, without having to use declarative obfuscation?

The wiki

https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Documentation

describes declarative obfuscation, but not what happens if this is not used.  How do I do it without declarative obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

Use any open source Obfuscation tool which Obfuscate compiled binaries and does not require you to add declarations, One is [Obfuscar](https://obfuscar.codeplex.com/)